# How to cache static background images in ASP.NET MVC 2 web site?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, caching

I would like to cache static background images in my ASP.NET MVC 2 web page.
What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Static images are already cached by the browser.

Comment: hmmm.. they don't seem to be, because i get that annoying flickering of the web site when loading

Comment: Flickering is not necessary occurring because images are not cached. Look with FireBug to analyze the HTTP traffic.

Comment: I checked the HTTP traffic and it clearly shows that the images take the most of the load time.